# Wy my AsyncTask not show progress dialog?

Tags: java, android-asynctask

```
package com.urban.map.services;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.urban.map.App;
import com.urban.map.database.Queries;
import com.urban.map.database.TestDB;

import org.richit.easiestsqllib.Column;
import org.richit.easiestsqllib.Datum;
import org.richit.easiestsqllib.EasiestDB;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class LoadDataService extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    public LoadDataService(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMax(100);
        pd.setMessage("Hello ");
        pd.setTitle("ASSSSSSSs");
        pd.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    int current_percent = 0;
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String time = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()/1000L);
        Queries q = App.getQueriesInstance(mContext);
        q.insertTime();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://100rad.ru/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        PostInterface service = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);
        Call<List<MapData>> call = service.getMap("full");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MapData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<MapData>> call, Response<List<MapData>> response) {
                List<MapData> newData = response.body();
                String max = String.valueOf(newData.size());
                Log.e("test","max "+max);
                for (int i = 0; i < newData.size(); i++) {
                    String auth_id = "368067266";
                    if (newData.get(i).getAuth().length() > 1) {
                        auth_id = newData.get(i).getAuth();
                    }
                    String store_id = newData.get(i).getStore_id();
                    String keywords = newData.get(i).getKey();
                    String telephone = newData.get(i).getTel();
                    String latitude = newData.get(i).getLat();
                    String longitude = newData.get(i).getLon();
                    String store_desc = newData.get(i).getStore_desc();
                    String store_name = newData.get(i).getStore_name();
                    String category_id = String.valueOf(newData.get(i).getCategory());
                    if (!category_id.equals("15")) {
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put("store_id", store_id);
                                 values.put("keywords", keywords);
                                 values.put("telephone", telephone);
                                 values.put("latitude", latitude);
                                 values.put("longitude", longitude);
                                 values.put("store_desc", store_desc);
                                 values.put("store_name", store_name);
                                 values.put("category_id", category_id);
                                 values.put("auth_id", auth_id);
                        q.insertStore(values);
                        values.clear();
                        List<Value> url = newData.get(i).getPhotos();
                        for (Value test : url) {
                            String data = test.getPhoto_url();
                            ContentValues pvalues = new ContentValues();
                                    pvalues.put("store_id", store_id);
                                    pvalues.put("photo_url", data);
                            q.insertPhoto(pvalues);
                            pvalues.clear();
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                    current_percent = (100 * count / Integer.parseInt(max));
                    Log.e("test", ""+current_percent);
                    publishProgress(current_percent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<MapData>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return "Sucess";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        pd.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("App", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstLogin", false);
        editor.apply();
        if (pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Its my mysql->sqlite code,i want show ProgressDialog while loading data,but for some reason it does not show it, although the download is in progress and the number of percentages goes to the log.
I have been working with this method not so long ago and I do not understand what I am doing wrong. My method is called from the main activity in this way
**new LoadDataService(this).execute();**

My gradle config:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
```

Comment: What kind of progress behavior do you want?  It looks like your `onResponse` handler is calling `publishProgress` in a loop, going from 0 to 100 before the system updates the UI.  You could have an indicator for "loading data..." (from the server) or for "parsing data..." (populating `Queries q`).

Comment: @Brian I need to create a dialog in which a line from 0 to 100 will be filled

Comment: How long does it take to go from `Log.e("test","max "+max);` to `Log.e("test", ""+100);`, in wall clock time?

Comment: @Brian , The entire loading process takes about 10-15 seconds, depending on the number of objects that are loaded